# Spring Security generate access token programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a web application for generating `access_token` via client_id and secret in the Database.

[Scenario]

1. User01 - request a new token
2. Service - get `client_id` then database which has status('Not Used')
3. Service - generate token with selected `client_id` and `secret`

I want to generate token in service-layer.

What I reference source code is `TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken()`.

But, that source code needs the Principal object. I don't have that data. Because that object contains `User01` User's data. So that's not right data.

How can I generate a token with client data in the Database?

Comment: First make the authentication token Domain and add the elements you want to add then you can UUID.randomUUID() to generate the tokens and then you can save in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Create the Authentication token Domain and add the elements. for example- id, token, user, and created date.

After that, you can save in the authenticationTokenRepository.

```
  AuthenticationToken authToken = new AuthenticationToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),user);
    AuthenticationToken savedAuthToken = 
    authenticationTokenRepository.save(authToken);
```